# Can I use all channels of a multi-channel ADC to sample an input signal?

Tags: analog, adc, signal, frequency, sampling

I am trying to evaluate an [ADC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7606_7606-6_7606-4.pdf) that can be used to digitize a simple analog signal of upto 1MHz frequency. This [ADC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7606_7606-6_7606-4.pdf) datasheet mentioned it has 8-input channels that are simultaneously sampled. What does it mean by simultaneously sampled?

Can I use all 8-channels to sample 1 input signal that can have maximum frequency of 1 MHz?

Comment: You would need to feed the signal through a delay line with 8 taps 5 us/8 = 625 ns apart. Each 625 ns segment could be almost 500 feet of correctly terminated coax cable, for example. Or have a word with the makers of SAW filters and delay lines. Getting the right ( > 2 MHz sampling) ADC will be much easier and simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simultaneously sampled means just that. It samples all channels at the same time. As opposed to sequencing through them very quickly. So feeding your one signal to multiple channels won't do anything for your sampling speed. You can do it, but you won't gain anything out of it.

On the other hand, if your ADC sequenced through the channels, then feeding your one input to multiple channels would increase the sampling rate since the sample taken by each channel would be at a different instant in time, and intervals between samples would be closer than if it was just one channel sampling repeatedly.

Comment: How do I figure out if it's possible to use the above ADC to digitize an analog signal of up to 1 MHz frequency?

Comment: It says on the front page 200ksps. Simultaneous sampling. So you can't do better than 200,000 samples per second. If it was not simultaneous sampling, then you could get 1.6Msps out of it by using all eight channels on one signal. For a signal with 1MHz bandwidth, you need a sampling rate at least double that (2Msps). Preferably 4Msps or 8Msps times that. So you need another ADC. This won't do.